# Uploading to Sketchfab loses texture

Tags: texturing

I am trying to upload a model to Sketchfab and I always lose the texture.  I have tried uploading a .blend file directly, as well as exporting to .OBJ and uploading to that.  In both cases, the model is not maintaining the texture / coloring.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edward

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's how Sketchfab works -- the model comes in without the texture and you have to add it back in manually within Sketchfab's interface. Of course, if you're using a Cycles procedural material, that will be lost as well and you'll have to try and replicate it within Sketchfab.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.  When exporting from Blender I should have set it to copy the texture file instead of using the default setting "Auto".  I thought I had done this, but when I restarted from scratch I saw that everything now worked - when I did things correctly.

Comment: where can i set this setting?